# devise not updating user, redirects to '/users' without any error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Whenever I try to update the user, I get redirected to `/users` with the edit form filled in but no errors.

**Users::RegistrationsController**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
 def update
    super
 end

 def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name,:property,:admin,:phone_number,:organization,:gender,:profile_pic,:birthday])
 end

...

end
```

**Rails Server Logs**

```
    Started PUT "/users" for ::1 at 2020-07-22 17:55:57 +0500
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iqpDtwA8U1jJ10dtaCV/eE0m96KHUa8G7tWrpOLA48AXYnUjT+6M2qwrwncjThvwQnQQycn/dNCWsbnsteJmhA==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Sohail ", "phone_number"=>"(11", "organization"=>"11", "email"=>"user@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND "users"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["email", "user@test.com"], ["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering users/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (3.9ms)
  StripeCustomer Load (4.6ms)  SELECT  "stripe_customers".* FROM "stripe_customers" WHERE "stripe_customers"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (97.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (15.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 681ms (Views: 310.2ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have messed a little with your parameters. You sent nested parameters on your form like this:

```
"user"=>{"name"=>"Sohail ", "phone_number"=>"(11", "organization"=>"11", "email"=>"user@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
```

However your permited parameters assume you are nesting everything on a `:account_update` key.

So you could either change the key sent on your form, or use this sanitizer:

```
def configure_account_update_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name,:property,:admin,:phone_number,:organization,:gender,:profile_pic,:birthday])
end
```